# Content-Security-Policy for Google Analytics v4

Tags: apache, google-analytics, virtualhost, content-security-policy

I do not have any tracking on my Google Analytics...
I do suspect that my Content-Security-Policy is wrong, even if the browser console is clean.
This is what I currently have:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.googletagmanager.com img-src: https://www.googletagmanager.com connect-src: https://www.googletagmanager.com;"
```

Any advise on this issue?
Best.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related

Answer (score 1):

`connect-src` and `img-src` should be without a colon. Also end each policy with a semicolon. But I believe you probably need some other hosts from Google aswell in your script-src. If you add a report-to into your CSP you can see what gets blocked.

I would also like to suggest to not allow unsafe inline js (if possible of course)

Answer (score 0):

Google suggests [some CSP policies](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/csp) by itself:

```
script-src:  https://*.googletagmanager.com
img-src:     https://*.google-analytics.com https://*.analytics.google.com https://*.googletagmanager.com
             https://*.g.doubleclick.net https://*.google.com https://*.google.<TLD>
connect-src: https://*.google-analytics.com https://*.analytics.google.com
             https://*.googletagmanager.com https://*.g.doubleclick.net https://*.google.com https://*.google.<TLD>
```

But in order to keep the HTTP header slim I still wonder how to know the [required TLDs](https://www.google.com/supported_domains) beforehand.

Comment: did you every figure out if all those TLD's are needed?

Comment: @RichardScarrott most of them were needed to cover all countries where users could originate from. Sadly there are no includes, this seems to be some design flaw in CSPs.
Also make sure your proxies [do support](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffer_size) such bloated headers.